# Error while installing mysqlclient for python in Windows 10

Tags: python, mysql, windows, server, installation

I use this command for installing MySQL client:
`pip install mysqlclient`

And then I see this problem:

> running build_ext
>
> building '_mysql' extension
>
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

---

> Cleaning up... Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Jayed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jayed\mysqlclient\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\Jayed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-l4c6dhkk-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jayed\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Jayed\mysqlclient
>   Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Jayed\pip\pip.log

Comment: The error tells you precisely what you need to do: **Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279**

Answer (score 0):

Actually I went down this path.  While I suppose you can find all the libraries and components you need to get the client to compile, it is telling you it can't find a compiled copy of the client and is trying to compile it to install it.
Follow the instructions here: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/  (it has notes about windows doing what you are describing) or download the wheel file (from downloads link on the page) and type

pip install mysqlclient.whl

and it will install without demanding C++ in order to use mysql with python.